# 'Cannot read property 'role' of null' error in authorization

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, postman, authorization

I am working on authorization and it shows this error:

```
Cannot read property 'role' of null
```

Authorization  code:

```
exports.authorizeRoles = (roles) => {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        user = req.user.role;

         isAllowed = false;
      
        user.roles.map((role) => {
      if (roles.includes(role)) {
        isAllowed = true;
      }
        });
        
   if (!isAllowed)
      return res.status(401).json({
        status: "failed",
        message: " You are not allowed to access this",
      });

    next();
  };
};
```

Route code:

```
router.route('/product').get(isAuthenticatedUser, authorizeRoles("admin"), getAllProducts)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add the full error message and specifically what line the error happens on.