# i am working on authorization and it shows error Cannot read property 'role' of null"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, authorization

i am working on authorization and it shows error Cannot read property 'role' of null"

my authorization code:

```
   exports.authorizeRoles = (roles) => {
        return (req, res, next) => {
            user = req.user.role;
    
             isAllowed = false;
          
            user.roles.map((role) => {
          if (roles.includes(role)) {
            isAllowed = true;
          }
            });
            
       if (!isAllowed)
          return res.status(401).json({
            status: "failed",
            message: " You are not allowed to access this",
          });
    
        next();
      };
    };
```

route code:

```
router.route('/product').get(isAuthenticatedUser, authorizeRoles("admin"), getAllProducts)
```

error : Cannot read property 'role' of null" please help me..!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error in authorization Cannot read property 'role' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70546169/error-in-authorization-cannot-read-property-role-of-null)

Comment: no this is not!

Answer (score 0):

is user object coming in your req try console on it

```
 exports.authorizeRoles = (roles) => {
        return (req, res, next) => {
            console.log(req.user)
            user = req.user.role;
    
             isAllowed = false;
          
            user.roles.map((role) => {
          if (roles.includes(role)) {
            isAllowed = true;
          }
            });
            
       if (!isAllowed)
          return res.status(401).json({
            status: "failed",
            message: " You are not allowed to access this",
          });
    
        next();
      };
    };
```

if you are passing it in query it should be coming in req.query field

Comment: i have tried this it shows undefined

Comment: is user obj is coming in req parameter ? try using a debugger . also  what exactly is isAuthenticatedUser doing can you update the question

Answer (score 0):

In the isAuthenticatedUser Method
Check whether you are recieving the user by console.log(req.user);
and if you are getting null or Undefined
then the token you are decoding must get the right id

example:
const decodedData = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

```
req.user = await User.findById(decodedData.id);

console.log(req.user);
```

So if in the above code, if you got right id in findById(decodeData.id);
then you will be error free!!
and if you still got error, try to console the decodeData, and req.user
and check where you are missing

the decodeData should get the right Key, check for spelling in the decodeData.id
it should not decodeData._id